# jQuery Problem with IE ... still works on Firefox & Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, internet-explorer-8

got a little problem with IE8 ...

The Code below works fine in Firefox and Chrome ...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[title=\"CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk[1].vorlauftemp_ist-shortText\"]").css("background-     color","red");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div title="CAPPL:LOCAL.L_hk[1].vorlauftemp_ist-shortText">Value</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If i want to use this Code in IE8 or below it crashes without any error message ...
Does anybody has a solution for this tricky problem?

P.S. to uninstall IE8 is noooo solution :D

Comment: Works in IE8 for me...http://jsfiddle.net/P8wdx/1/

Comment: If you put your jQuery selector in single quotes, you won't need to escape the double quotes.  :-)

Comment: btw, you can use ' instead of \". It does confuse you less if you use an editor without syntax highlighting.

Comment: @anothershrubery: in a 'real' IE it wont work ... tried with IE8 and the TryIt Editor of http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @Andreas.. what do you mean by 'real' IE?

Comment: When i execute the code within a IE ^^"

Comment: In the link I posted it DOES work in IE, how do you think jsfiddle renders the code?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[title=CAPPL\\:LOCAL\\.L_hk\\[1\\]\\.vorlauftemp_ist-shortText]").css({"background-color" : "red"});
});
```

it seems IE7/IE8 compatibility mode still needs the special characters in the attribute value **escaped** using double backslashes. also note it works without escaping the `_` and the quotes before and after the title are not required

from the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

> If you wish to use any of the
>   meta-characters ( such as
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^{|}~ ) as a
>   literal part of a name, you must
>   escape the character with two
>   backslashes: `\\`. For example, if you
>   have an element with id="foo.bar", you
>   can use the selector `$("#foo\\.bar")`.
>   The W3C CSS specification [contains the complete set of rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) regarding valid
>   CSS selectors.

Comment: Unitl yet i always used the TryIt Editor from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_test. When i Execute the code of yours in Firefox it works, but in IE it won't.

Comment: Just tried this in IE9 and it didn't work. An odd problem indeed.

Comment: @Rory, @Andreas it's working locally for me IE7 & 8, and works in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/mPXKx/) - can't speak for IE9, but I've updated the answer with some references

Comment: @clairesuzy its really weird ... when I use http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/mPXKx/ in IE8 it works ... BUT applying it to my code it's still not working :(

Comment: @Andreas it is weird one - maybe rendering mode? what's your Doctype?

Comment: Im using   <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> at the moment

Comment: The problem was indeed that I saw the code in IE8 compability mode ... Is there any chance to tell IE8 not to use this mode??

Comment: cool.. there is a meta tag you can use to force either IE8 or "Edge" (all future versions) - [read more](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/beyonddoctype)

Comment: Most browsers seem to be tolerant of attribute names not having their special characters escaped, but iE7 and iE8+iE7 compatiblity simply don't match them.  You need to escape them anywhere they occur to keep iE7 happy, even if they work withoue escaping in other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The IE problem is a combination of having square brackets and a colon in the selector.

This fiddle works in IE (no : or []): http://jsfiddle.net/aM9nX/4/

This fiddle works in IE (has []): http://jsfiddle.net/4nfHW/1/

This fiddle does not (has : and []): http://jsfiddle.net/xghtg/3/

Is it possible for you to remove those characters?

Comment: I could remove them, but I need exactly these variable to communicate with an control panel behind a server.  If I remove them bevore, I can't add it anymore at the exact position ...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xghtg/3/ worked fine in IE8, meaning the nackground was green when opened in IE8.. I dont think `[]` and `:` are an issue..

Comment: @Aravindan You're right, http://jsfiddle.net/xghtg/3/ works in IE8, but does not work in IE7 or IE9 (which i tested in initially)... weird?

Answer (score 0):

try .css({"background-color","red"})
I dont know if thats the issue but its caused me grief before ( were missing the {s )

Comment: sorry .css({"background-color" : "red"} although that still may not be the issue, I am trying to recreate the error atm :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's a typo, but the spaces in "background-    color" will cause it not to work.

Comment: Yeah, I addressed that in my fiddle above, but because of the spaces it wouldn't have worked in any browser.

Comment: @Andreas You should update the question with the spaces removed. :)

Answer (score 0):

@anothershrubery is right.. it does work in IE8 http://jsfiddle.net/ha44p/

you misspelled the css property background-color, that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly working on FF, Safari, Chrome, IE9, IE8, **except on IE7**.

See for yourself. I changed \" to '. As it is much more proper thank escaping it.

http://jsfiddle.net/p2ReV/